# Remove data by percentile grouping by another column

Tags: python, pandas

I can remove data above 95 percentile from a column using:

```
df[df.value < df.value.quantile(.95)]
```

How can I remove data above 95 percentile grouped by another column?

So if I have a dataframe like below, I want to remove row 1 because it is above 95 percentile within type A.

```
Row  type  value 
1    A     100000
2    A     0.1
3    A     0.3
4    B     10
5    B     11
```

Edit: I would like to remove above 95 percentile data for all 'Type' - removing above 95 percentile for Type A, Type B etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
df[df['value'].lt(df.groupby('type')['value'].transform(lambda s: s.quantile(.95)))]
```

or, shorted form:

```
df[df['value'].lt(df.groupby('type')['value'].transform('quantile', .95))]
```

output:

```
   Row type  value
1    2    A    0.1
2    3    A    0.3
3    4    B   10.0
```

Comment: `df[df.value < df.groupby('type')['value'].transform('quantile', .95)]` Is what you're looking for I believe.

Comment: Mine simplifies to not use the lambda :P

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution, `.groupby` and `.apply` to filter rows within each group:

```py
df.groupby('type', group_keys=False).apply(
    lambda g: g[g.value < g.value.quantile(.95)]
)
```

```py
   Row type  value
1    2    A    0.1
2    3    A    0.3
3    4    B   10.0
```

---

Previous solution - if you want to remove data above 95 percentile **only in type A**:

```py
vals_a = df.loc[df.type.eq('A'), 'value']

df[df.value.lt(vals_a.quantile(.95)) & df.type.eq('A') | df.type.ne('A')]
```

**Result:**

```py
   Row type  value
1    2    A    0.1
2    3    A    0.3
3    4    B   10.0
4    5    B   11.0
```